# How do you figure out the prepositional object with a clause final preposition?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, linguistics, prepositional-objects

First time asking a question, sorry for any weirdness.
The best way for me to illustrate might be with some examples. I believe all 4 of the following are both grammatical and would be commonly used in English.

1. This is the place I was talking about.
2. That is the organization I am a part of.
3. This is the problem I was having trouble with.
4. That is exactly what I was hoping for.

Are the objects of the preposition place/organization/problem/what? Or this/that/this/that? Is there a good rule of thumb to figure it out? In my experience, you can usually make a question of a prepositional phrase and answer it with the object, like "I went onto the roof" can be "where did I go onto?" "the roof" or "I ran into the store" can be "where did I run into?" "the store". But the answer to "what was I having trouble with?" could be "this" or "(this) problem". And the answer to "what was I hoping for?" is "that". Does the last one even have a prepositional phrase?

Comment: Within the relative clauses, the object of the preposition is the antecedent, i.e. "place", "organization", "problem" and "what". For example, in 1. the relative clause is "I was talking about __ " where gap is object of "about", and understood as "place".

Comment: In all the first three examples, optional ***that*** hasn't been included, and in principle the last one could be rephrased as ***That** is exactly **that which** I was hoping for.* So they can all feature "relativisers".

Comment: The fact that the antecedents ("place", "organization" etc.) are predicative complements of "this" and "that" does not affect their status as object of the preposition.

Comment: Your first three are object relative clauses; the **relative pronoun** is the object: ***that** I was talking about* —> *I was talking about **that***. Your last one is a nominal relative or a fused relative clause; the relative pronoun "lives inside": *what I was hoping for* —> *the thing **that** I was hoping for* —> *I was hoping for **that***.